Exporting raster with color table adds categories from 0 up to 255 with terra
I want to add a colour table to a terra raster object. It works, however, when looking at the raster in QGIS, it added a bunch of unwanted categories (from 0 to 255).
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncols=3, nrows=2, vals=c(10:12, 23:25))
coltab(r) <- data.frame(values=c(10:12, 23:25), cols=rainbow(6))
plot(r)
writeRaster(r, filename = 'test.tif', datatype = 'INT1U', overwrite = TRUE)

Example from this post.
Here is the raster imported in QGIS. You can see in the screenshot the categories 10 to 12 that have the colors, but also 9, 13, 14, etc. that have black color.
Is there a way to properly export the raster with color table but not adding the categories with black color?

I guess that the 0 to 255 is the 255 colors (0 to 254) + an alpha channel (the last value or 255)

This all goes via the GDAL library, and that only supports 256-colour colour tables.
https://gdal.org/en/stable/doxygen/classGDALColorTable.html
There might be another raster format that only saves some entries in a colour table but I'm not sure which. QGIS might always pad them back out to 256 anyway.
You can delete them from the QGIS symbology dialog, but that's in the QGIS layer properties, and doesn't change the GeoTIFF itself.

Not sure I understand because it seems this is possible with other tiff files such as this one https://www.donneesquebec.ca/recherche/dataset/utilisation-du-territoire/resource/562e43ed-bd4c-4303-8c4e-2dc807e8a7e7

So is there a way to produce a similar tiff file but with terra? There are much more than 256 colours. Dataype = Int16, RepresentationType=THEMATIC, 1 band min = 0, max = 32767

Not with the command line GDAL version I've got. That large land use tiff has "ColorInterp=Gray" under gdalinfo and no colour palette. QGIS shows it as categorical though, but only when read from the same location as the various "sidecar" files, showing that the categorical info is not in the TIFF itself. I think we're seeing QGIS use the  .vat.dbf file https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259389/how-to-read-a-raster-value-table-vat-in-qgis  which looks like an ESRI extension? It should be possible to write a minimal VAT from R with just your table entries in... Hmmm...

I see. The coltab is actually writing the info inside the tiff, while the land use tiff has other files with the palette. Are you saying that it's not possible to do something similar (as in the land use file) with the colour palette example above using terra?

It should be possible to write a .VAT.DBF file using the foreign package write.dbf function but I can't get it to work exactly, and not sure why. I get the descriptions for the cell values but the colours aren't set....

BTW, seems it's ArcGIS data format, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273372/how-to-access-the-attribute-table-of-a-tif-map-in-r and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840178/how-to-write-a-raster-with-rat-factors-in-r-raster-package. Never the less interesting topic/question :). In the very past when I received the ArcGIS generated rasters, rather it was a standard TIFF with kind of predefined layer style, which was readable by QGIS.

Here is a work-around that uses a value attribute table for the colors:
library(terra)
#terra 1.8.5
r <- rast(ncols=3, nrows=2, vals=c(10:12, 23:25))
levels(r) <- data.frame(id=c(10:12, 23:25), t(col2rgb(rainbow(6))))
x <- writeRaster(r, filename = 'test.tif', overwrite = TRUE)
plot(x)


coltab(x)
#[[1]]
#  value red green blue alpha
#1    10 255     0    0   255
#2    11 255   255    0   255
#3    12   0   255    0   255
#4    23   0   255  255   255
#5    24   0     0  255   255
#6    25 255     0  255   255




This works in R, but if I import it in QGIS, it doesn't show the colors. coltab(r) is a step in the right direction, but the problem remains with the categories from 0 to 255.
